# Extract first value from each list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract

I have this dictionary which is being returned from a function:

```
{'Revenue':TotalRevExInt, 'Expenses':Expenses, 'IntExpense':NetIntExp, 'Depr&Amort':DeprAndAmort}
```

Each item is a list of 10 numbers e.g.

```
Expenses = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I'm stumped at trying to extract the first number from each list in the dictionary, so the output would essentially be [1,1,1,1]. I've had a look around but cant seem to find the right answer. Does anyone know the best way to approach this? Cheers.

Comment: `out = [v for v in d.values()]` or just `d.values`

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: aren't dictionaries by definition unordered?

Comment: Only since Python 3.7 it's safe to assume that your `dict` instance behaves like an `OrderedDict`, but it's still not widely recommended to assume this property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the first value of each list, you could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate on your dict values and then use indexing on each list to access the first element. Of course, this assumes that the order of the output might not matter:

```
[list_of_values[0] for list_of_values in my_dict.values()]
```

**Note:** Since Python 3.7 you should be able to assume that your `dict` instance behaves like an `OrderedDict`, but it's still not widely recommended to assume this property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use .values()
and have something like this

```
ans = []
for i in Expenses.values():
    ans.append(i[0])
```